# How do I remove icons from the Unity launcher using a script?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, uninstall

After a fresh install of 11.04 I have a script that does a few useful things.
Is there a way to remove the LibreOffice, Ubuntu One etc icons from the Unity launcher using command line so I can put it in my script?

Answer (score 5):

- Get the list of launcher items:

  ```
  gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
  ```

  This will return something like:

  ```
  ['nautilus-home.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop', 'gedit.desktop']
  ```

  which you can manipulate in your script (eg. using *sed*), and then
- Set the launcher item list:

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['gimp.desktop']"
  ```

  Don't forget the quotes.

Comment: I've had chance to try this now but it doesn't work. If it type: 

gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites

I get this:

['nautilus-home.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice-impress.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop', 'ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk.desktop']

If i then type:

gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['firefox.desktop']"

Then check it again with gsettings get it seems to have changed, but after a reboot nothing alters and another gsettings get shows the original list?

Comment: Then you probably haven't installed the (default) package `libdconf0` - it works just fine here.

Comment: did an apt-get install libdconf0 and it says its already the newest version. any other ideas why this isnt working on a fresh install?

Comment: Didn't work for me either. I'll take a look around

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
unity --replace
```

after

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['firefox.desktop']"
```

working on 12.04

Comment: +1 Works for me with 14.04, too.  However I needed to daemonize it using `( unity --replace & )` from within a gnome terminal to update everything properly without risk of bad side-effects.