# How to force Unity reload ~/.local/share/applications/

Tags: unity, shortcuts

Let's say I changed/added some `myapp.desktop` file at `~/.local/share/applications/`.
For some time Ubuntu Unity will still show me old applications shortcuts at Unity lens under Ubuntu button. It will take some time (or just a one restart) to get applications list updated there.

How I can force Unity reload `~/.local/share/applications` and reflect shortcuts correctly in lens?

Comment: Have you tried `unity --reset`?

Comment: Correction. It should just be `unity`. Press alt+F2 and type in the command.

Comment: Yes. It didn't help. It still shows old application name after `unity` or `unity --reset` (which was before I modified myapp.desktop file).

Comment: Odd, it seems to be working fine when I do the exact same thing you're doing. Have made sure the `.desktop` file is executable?

Comment: It works only after log off/restart. Try just to change the name of existing application inside the desktop file. Don't change anything else. For ex, add " Test" to the name of some existing app. Now press Ubuntu button and start typing application name - it still shows old name without " Test" for me. I reproduced it on both work and home machines and on wife's laptop. I think it's about 100% reproducable.

Comment: Confirmed. It is reproducible.

Comment: Analogous question for newer Ubuntus: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12118/how-do-i-refresh-gnome-3-applications.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

A little late, but i stumbled upon this thread before finding a solution, atleast to my problem, googling something related, nearly giving up.

As per this guide [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles), don't just edit or create your `.desktop` files in `/usr/local/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. Instead, create the file somewhere else and use

```
desktop-file-install <your_file.desktop>
```

to add the file.

E.g. you create `~/myapp.desktop` and do

```
desktop-file-install --dir=$HOME/.local/share/applications ~/myapp.desktop
```

Existing files of the same name will be overwritten and unity updated, you can use `--delete-original` if the source is not needed anymore, or

```
sudo desktop-file-install ~/myapp.desktop
```

to install it for all users.

Comment: +1 this works.  A rough edit script using this recipe is at https://gist.github.com/hilbix/f468fcbb15c3f68670d8

Comment: just putting a copy of the .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications worked for me-

Comment: I usually manually edit the file and add it to `.local/share/applications/`. Tried using the command with `--delete-original` and I got a warning: `warning: key "Keywords[uk]" is a list and does not have a semicolon as trailing character, fixing`. The result was the source file deleted and nothing copied to the target directory. Evil OS... basically nuked my file and I had to create a new one from scratch.

Comment: I still get the issue OP noticed even when doing this.

Comment: I also still get the issue OP noticed even when doing this (and even after restarting) (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: This also works with plasma ( kde ).  But, what does desktop-file-install do other than copying the file contents into /usr/share/applications ( in case of sudo ) ?

Comment: I put the original desktop files under a local version control in subversion and use this method to deploy them. This makes it easier to deploy on new OS installs. On caveat I noticed is that the desktop may not refresh the first time you hit the `Super` key but does the second time.

Comment: This solutions only works for me, if I go to `dir=$HOME/.local/share/application` then right click to the corresponding `application.desktop` and allow the permission of the execution.

Answer (score 25):

`sudo update-desktop-database` will refresh the `.desktop` database.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Running Ubuntu 16.04. I still don't see on the launcher icon the changes made in the .desktop file.

Comment: This command only updates MIME type databases. It does not update any other changes. See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/update-desktop-database.1.html

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: works for me with sudo

Comment: Worked like a charm on Ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 18):

The way to do this is to run the command

```
killall unity-scope-home
```

after opening the dash the process is started automatically again.

The correct icons are then displayed...

Comment: Does not work at my side.  I removed a `.desktop` file and it still shows up in `compiz` launch bar.

Comment: Well, stuck with [BUG 1287663](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1287663) the [solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/146373/164798) was to use `gsettings set` followed by `( unity --replace & )`

Comment: I don't know what you mean with compiz launch bar?! I thought you were talking about the dash?

Comment: Works fine for me, Applications are listed again

Comment: Any alternatives in 15.10? I'm getting `unity-scope-home: no process found`

Answer (score 8):

According with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/68803/147044) (and you can find many others in the same sense), unfortunately there seems to be no command to let the unity-applications-daemon refresh its application cache. But I can confirm that unity will automatically detect any changes with `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`. If these changes are not immediately available, try logging out and in again to refresh it.

Comment: Yeah, it will automatically detect .... in an hour ...

Comment: @vladimir As I said, if you want the changes immediately available, try logging out and in again to refresh it.

Comment: I fully got your answer and probably will accept it. You understand downsides of logging off - all opened apps closed. It's not a solution, it's a workaround and not a user friendly one. Are you developer by any chance? If yes, could you please point me to the daemon sources? I guess this is it: [unity-lens-applications daemon.vala](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity-lens-applications/trunk/view/head:/src/daemon.vala)

Answer (score 5):

This answer does not involve a desktop restart.

---

Though quite late, there's a utility command to update the desktop database cache named `update-desktop-database`.

Updating stuffs added in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`, use:

```
>> update-desktop-database
```

Updating stuffs addded in global ones, like `/usr/share/ubuntu/applications`, `/usr/share/gnome/applications`, `/usr/share/applications`, etc., use:

```
>> sudo update-desktop-database
```

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Some applications might stop working properly after this command. Chrome, for example, became totally black.**

```
unity --replace
```

Comment: Could you clarify your warning(?)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, fixed when restart. I use ubuntu 16.04

I usually create `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications/` if I want to share the desktop files with other users and `~/.local/share/applications` if for only one user. And I usually restart.