# How to refresh Unity's applications list after installing an app (using 16.04)?

Tags: unity

so I just installed an app available on default and 3rd-party repositories --via apt-get--.

My problem is that Unity icons for these apps doesn't show in the Applications list. I looked at Ubuntu Software manager and nothing there too.

If I install the app via Ubuntu Software manager, I don't get the problem.

The icons will only show up --once I reboot my machine--. Any ideas on how can I refresh my Applications list without rebooting/logging out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rebooting is too much, you just need to logout and login.

Comment: See: [How to force Unity reload ~/.local/share/applications/](http://askubuntu.com/q/375975)